# Send cookie with the request headers

Tags: jquery

I am trying to send my cookie to an external url and I cant see my cookie is not set in the request header and which is causing error throwing from the external server

Below is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello-Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax({ 
            headers: { 
                "Accept ": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                "MY_COOKIE": $.cookie("MY_COOKIE"),
            }, 
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'external_url',
            success: function(data){        
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });

    });

    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Any idea, why the cookie is not getting set in the request header while calling the external url, but getting the data correctly when trying from the browser.

Thanks,
Prats

Comment: For one, `MY_COOKIE: ...` is not a recognized HTTP header.

Comment: request always have the cookie with it.